# Can't open jupyter notebook from anaconda with a default python installed

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have both pythons in C:\Python34 and in C:\Anaconda3. Recently I use every python environment like spyder or qtconsole from Anaconda Navigator. They all work well. But When I try to open notebook. It somehow shows me the default notebook in   C:\Python34 but not the one in C:\Anaconda3.

I've checked sys.path of the tools from Anaconda Navigator and find only notebook's path is in C:\Python34, while others' are in C:\Anaconda3. How can I open the notebook in C:\Anaconda3 or change the default path of it?

Comment: Install the Notebook into C:\Anaconda3 using Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Jupyter looks for a *kernelspec* to tell it how to launch the kernel, the process that runs your code. You can see the kernelspecs it finds by running `jupyter kernelspec list` in a command prompt. If you installed one from your other Python installation, Jupyter will run that even if Jupyter itself is installed in Anaconda. Info on installing IPython kernelspecs is [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html).

Comment: @darthbith: Sorry, I didn't follow you. Is your answer just a question or a recommendation? I had installed python3 and the notebook before I installed anaconda. Then the problem occurred.

Comment: Right now, you have two versions of Python installed, and Notebook is installed into C:\Python34. You need to install Notebook into the version of Python at C:\Anaconda3.